# Proof that for $\alpha > 0$ and $\tau \geq 0$ , P($s$) = $(s+\alpha+ e^{-s\tau})$ has no solution less than zero

Tags: transcendental-equations

P($s$) = $(s+\alpha+ e^{-s\tau})$

Proof that for $\alpha > 0$ and $\tau \geq 0$ the polynomial has no solution less than zero.

I am having difficulty proving that for $\alpha > 0$ and $\tau \geq 0$, the polynomial below doesn't lead to a real negative part (in case the solution was imaginary).

$s+\alpha+ e^{-s\tau} = 0$

Comment: In case τ = 0, P(s) = s + α +1, which gives -α-1 is a negative solution. I guess you should modify the condition to τ > 0